multipart-post in upgrade from Rails 5.1 to 7.1
I've got this app that was upgraded from Rails 5.1 to 7.1 recently.
multipart-post was in the Gemfile.lock in 5.1:
faraday (0.12.0.1)
  multipart-post (>= 1.2, < 3)

multipart-post (2.0.0)

But it wasn't in the 5.1 Gemfile, and it isn't anywhere in 7.1. It was used only used one time in 5.1 in API code:
require 'net/http/post/multipart'

    (etc)
    File.open(file_name) do |file|
      req = Net::HTTP::Post::Multipart.new url.path,
        "sample" => UploadIO.new(file, "audio/mp3", file_name),
        (etc)

In it's documentation it says "bundle add multipart-post" to install, but I was wondering if any other insight on it, as the api code is generally beyond my capacity

You can see from the lockfile it multipart-post was a dependency for the faraday gem.  It was removed in 2022 https://github.com/lostisland/faraday/commit/cb47eca810c15512c91379f0d0a0fd9dcf143566

Any objections to adding it to Gemfile then, so the one line works?

They moved the multipart to the faraday multipart gem, but I’d check to see if there is any advantage to using that or just add back the multipart-post to the gem file

i did Gem 'multipart-post', as the api is acrcloud (song fingerprinting), listed in the Ruby tab at https://docs.acrcloud.com/reference/identification-api ... see if that resolved it tomorrow, I appreciate that, thank you
